# Haskell sort with operator

Tags: sorting, haskell

I want to implement a function

```
> ssort (<) [2,8,4,6,3,9,7]
  [2,3,4,6,7,8,9]
> ssort (>) [2,8,4,6,2,6,7]
  [9,8,7,6,4,3,2]
```

first i think i should have detect the operator,this is how i do it,

```
ssort [] =[]
ssort op xs |op ==(<) = minVal : ssort rest
            |op ==(>) = maxVal : ssort rest1
    where minVal =minimum xs
          maxVal =maximum xs
          rest =delete minVal xs
          rest1 = delete maxVal xs
```

and it gives an error:"parse error on input ??'

so i do this,and it gives same error

```
ssort [] =[]
ssort op xs |op 4 5 ==True = minVal : ssort rest
            |op 4 5 ==False = maxVal : ssort rest1
    where minVal =minimum xs
          maxVal =maximum xs
          rest =delete minVal xs
          rest1 = delete maxVal xs
```

how can i solve the problem?Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't compare functions, so `op == (<)` will always be rejected by the compiler.

The good news is that you don't have to detect what `op` actually is. You can instead assume that it provides meaningful results every time it is used.

From your code, it looks like you want to use some selection sort. For that you need a custom `minimum` function which takes `op` as an additional argument, and returns the minimum according to `op`. You could start by implementing that.

Note that, in the libraries, we already have `minimumBy` and `sortBy` that can be used with an arbitrary `op`. E.g., you could use something like

```
where minVal = minimumBy cmp xs
      cmp x y | op x y = LT
              | op y x = GT
              | otherwise = EQ
```